# Conserving RAM in java by using references to objects

Tags: java, memory

I know some about java, and a lot about the lower level functions of a computer, so I'm always looking for ways to conserve ram. I'm also a fan of dwarf fortress, so I've been trying to get some similar system working. So, what I want to do is to make multiple tiles, assign them some type of material, and all the tiles with the same type of material share the same material object. I drew a little picture to illustrate it: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQex1.png)
Does java do this automatically? or do I have to implement it by myself? If I make two copies of the material properties, is there a way to merge them both into one?

Thank you for responding.

Comment: "*Does java do this automatically?*" No. Object pool pattern.

Comment: could you please clarify what an "object pool pattern" is? or how to implement one? I looked online, and a lot of websites talk about using it only when new objects are 'expensive to create'. None of them really talk about using it to conserve ram. Is there another name for it I should be googling?

Comment: You don't necessarily need object pooling. You could make the data static, so it would be tied to the class. Then new instances of the material would all reference the same object. You're question is a bit vague though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a material.

```
interface Material{
    void render( Context c);
}
```

Then you have some instance of the material.

```
class Concrete implements Material{
    static Texture concreteTexture = loadConcreteTexture();
    Texture texture;
    public Concrete(){
      texture = concreteTexture();
    }
    void render(Context c){
        //do stuff with texture.
    }
}
```

In this case there would be 1 concrete texture for all of the instances of concrete, and it gets loaded when the class gets loaded. The texture gets assigned in the constructor, but you might use a factory method instead that would create new materials and load/assign the assets.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure i understand your question, but lets say each tile is represented by an object and the material is represented by a shared object then you can use singleton pattern in java:

```
interface MatType{
    String getType();
    void draw();
}

class Cement implements MatType{
    private static Cement cement = null;
    
    private string type = "Cement";

    /*some cement properties here*/

    private Cement(){}

    /*
By using this method you will get always the same
        object which will be shared between all objects
        that reference it.
    */ 
    public static Cement getInstance(){
            if (cement == null)
                cement = new Cement();
            return cement;
    }
    
    String getType(){
        return type;
    }
    
    void draw(){
    //draw
    }
    
}

class Tile{
    MatType type = null;
    
    /*tile properties*/
    
    public Tile(String t){
        if (t.equals("Cement"))
            type = (MatType)Cement.getInstance(); /*casting is for clarification only*/
        if (t.equals("Iron"))
            type = Iron.getInstance(); /*same logic of Cement*/
        .
        .
        .
    }
    
    String getType(){
        return type.getType();
    }
    
    void draw(){
        type.draw();
    }
    
}
```